# Timing belt change

Tags: vw, golf, timing-belt, scheduled-maintenance

When does my timing belt need changing?

I have a mark 7 vw golf 2 litre dti 64 plate only done 28 000 miles and have been told I need to change my timing belt. Could you help with the above question

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this matrix](https://pics.tdiclub.com/data/500/2014_Golf.pdf), the timing belt on a 2014 VW Golf TDI has a belt change schedule or 130k miles. The linked matrix shows all of your maintenance schedules, in case you're wondering.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a VW factory matrix online, and the OP didn't state the car's model year. At least for the 2014 2.0 TDI engine, VW apparently only gives a mileage trigger, saying the belt is a "lifetime" part until the stated mileage is reached.

The 2.0 TDI is an interference motor; if the belt breaks or the tensioners fail, the results will be mechanically ugly and expensive to repair.

I distrust the labeling of parts as "lifetime," suspecting that the marketing people have taken over the engineering desk. Given the serious consequences of a belt or tensioner failure, I'd change the belt and tensioners after 7 years, even if the mileage limit has not been reached.